# How to customise the response body when "401 Unauthorized" occurred?

Tags: helidon

Instead of an empty response body when "401 Unauthorized" occurs, I want to add the other information into the response (e.g timestamp, a message), how can I override it?

**Expectation:**

```
HTTP status: 401 Unauthorized
Response body:
{
  "timestamp": 1234567890,
  "message": "Your access token was expired"
}
```

`I'm using the Helidon MP v2.5.5`

Comment: If you are using Jersey, have you explored ExceptionMapper? ExceptionMappers in Jersey allow you to control the response for any unhandled exception thrown during response lifecycle within JAXRs (not container)

Answer (score 0):

To customize the response body when a "401 Unauthorized" error occurs in Helidon, you can handle the error in the error handling mechanism provided by Helidon. You can write your custom logic inside the error handling mechanism to return the desired response.

Here is an example code to demonstrate the same:

```
server.addErrorHandler(401, ex -> 
    ServerResponse
        .status(401)
        .header("Content-Type", "text/plain")
        .send("Unauthorized Error Occurred!")
);
```

This code will return a response with a 401 status code and the response body "Unauthorized Error Occurred!" whenever a 401 error is encountered in the server.

Comment: The Helidon MP is for `Java` and it seems that there is no exception was thrown when 401 occurs

Comment: My bad... edited for Helidon.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [ExceptionMapper](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/ext/ExceptionMapper.html) class in javax/jakarta. You can create a Provider that implements the ExceptionMapper using BadRequestException. Then override the *toResponse* method of ExceptionMapper. That way you can customize the response.

Some code doing this could look like this:

```
@Provider
@NoArgsConstructor
public class <YourExceptionHandler> implements ExceptionMapper<BadRequestException> {
  @Override
  public Response toResponse(BadRequestException exception){
    <custom code>
    return Response.status(<status>).entity(<custom code>).build()
  }
}
```

In my case, for the *custom code* part I instance a class that handles the error's status, error message, etc...